# Web-Inspector: How can I find a DOM-Element in the hierarchy that sets a background-color?

Tags: html, css, dom, web-inspector

is there any function or extension that allows to find the element that's styles for example the background-color in a DOM-Hierarchy using the Web-Inspector of any browser?

Let's think about a DOM-Tree that might look like this:

```css
.div3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="div0">
  <div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
      <div class="div3">
        <div class="div4">
          <div class="div5">
            <div class="div6">
              <div class="div7">
                <div class="div8">
                  Some Text
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The element select tool will select .div8. Now you have to go up the tree and manual search the first div that's setting the green color. Is there any tree-search available? e.g. Find first div that applies style "background-color" up the tree? The searchbox only finds styles that are applied the current DOM-Element.

Comment: Can you explain why you have such requirement? I am just curious to know.

Comment: In a complex website (or web-application) there are tons of DOM-Elements that have specific styles. May be a color, overflow or any other style. When developing you might want to know who is applying an overflow: hidden to some of the divs (and make things look weird). There are many styles applied, so eye "debugging" may took some time to find those containers.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with just the web-inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Select all element parents, loop them and check `background-color`. In web inspector write code in `console` tab

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var parents = $('.div8').parents();

  $.each(parents, function() {
    if ($(this).css('background-color') != 'transparent' && $(this).css('background-color') != 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') {
      console.log($(this).attr('class') + ':' + $(this).css('background-color'));
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.div3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div0">
  <div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
      <div class="div3">
        <div class="div4">
          <div class="div5">
            <div class="div6">
              <div class="div7">
                <div class="div8">
                  Some Text
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your output is giving me `div7` instead of `div3` - not sure why to be honest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm not looking for a javascript solution. I know how to do this using javascript (and jquery). I'd like to find such element using the web-inspector (without writing code). May be there is an extension or a function I missed so far.

Comment: @SuperNova You asked for function - you got function.

Comment: you could just click on each parent in the heirarchy and check the `computed` tabs?

Comment: Fixed Chrome bug that returns `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` instead of `transparent`

Comment: @Justinas May be it's because english is not my native language: I meant _application_-function/application-feature e.g. toolbar button or short cut that activates a "function" in web-inspector.

Comment: @Jhecht Yes, I'm looking for a possibility to do a simple computer driven search for this.

Comment: From the web inspector console you can get the current element from `$0`. You can loop through all parents by pasting something like `for (current = $0; current = current.parentElement; current) {
    console.log(current);
}` (no jQuery). If you can log the background color, rather than the whole element,