# How can I change the Google Sheets background with CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-sheets, web-inspector, stylish

I want the grey area (in the red circle in my screenshot) to be `#000`, but I can't find a good selector for it.

[Google Sheets screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqs6q.png)

Currently, the background blinks `red` for less than a second and then turns grey. I painted another area green to be sure my Stylish Chrome extension is working.

```css
#docs-chrome {
  background: green;
}

#docs-edit-container, #docs-editor, .grid-container {
  background: red !important;
}
```

Spent 20 minutes in Devtools. I just can't find it. The DOM of Google Sheets is pretty complex.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51427484/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37560451/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to color the whole thing, then try

```
    .goog-inline-block.grid4-inner-container{
         background-color:red;
    }
```

The entire sheet uses a single class to change color, there is just one color: white, even in the unused area controlled by `grid4-inner-container`

Comment: This selector seems to match areas in front of, not behind the table. https://i.imgur.com/5DfI5VW.png The grey background is still there and the table is partially hidden behind a red rectangle.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your issue on my end, the background color and cell color is by default white in my case, not gray.